# Are all Semantic Web technology questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Semantic Web technologies include for instance SPARQL, RDF, etc.

Are all questions about these technologies OK? *(I hope yes, personally)*

Or are these questions accepted only if they are used on open datasets? *(which might be hard to tell)*

Comment: Related: [Are (RDF) vocabularies/ontologies on-topic?](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/233/are-rdf-vocabularies-ontologies-on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, they generally should be on topic here on OpenData.SX.

(Disclaimer: I currently write my PhD thesis on a Semantic Web topic, so I might be a bit biased.)

There could be edge cases that might be off-topic. When the question deals with a complex programming problem related to a Semantic Web technology, it might be a better fit for StackOverflow (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparql with currently 1,439
questions).

On the other hand, questions about Linked Data (https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-data) are a perfect fit for OpenData.SX.